# Upload Image, Crop & Resize

Tags: php, ajax, image, upload

What is the best way to upload an image, save it temporary, and let some user resize and crop it in some ajaxy interface?

Any serious librarys with PHP?

Comment: These are three separate issues.  Uploading and having a database to keep track of the images, an "ajaxy" interface for cropping/resizing, and the backend libraries for PHP to do the actual work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Brad is right, separate your problem into its independent pieces.

I had some luck with [Imagemagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/api.php) as the backend. Also [see here](http://php.net/manual/en/book.imagick.php).

For Ajaxy UI tricks, JQuery seems to be the stock advice, although I've hardly used it myself.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than storing temporary, I would store it permanently and do some *default* resizing/cropping initially. Then, if user wants to edit the default results, there would be additional interface for this.

Users are often lazy and it is OK to have some default processing for such users.

Answer (score 1):

You can upload an image and store the it (the original) in the filesystem permanently. You can then use an image manipulation library (I would recommend having a look at [phpThumb](http://phpthumb.sourceforge.net/))  to do the resizing. As for the interface, you can use jQuery or any other user interface library of your choice (see [this link](http://plugins.jquery.com/plugin-tags/crop)). The interface would merely allow user to specify the resize/crop parameters -- phpThumb will do the rest.

Answer (score 1):

For a PHP Image Transformation Library, I always found [class.upload.php](http://www.verot.net/php_class_upload.htm) to be quite handy. It handles resizing/cropping/filling and other basic transformations quite well.